# How can i call my autosys job from file watcher job

Tags: autosys

I want to create a file watcher which will call my autosys job once matched file will available at given location.

Answer (score 1):

Define following jobs and set the condition of the CMD job as Success of FW job

```
# FW Job
insert_job: data_file_fw_job
job_type: FW
machine: localhost
watch_file: “/home/user/data_input.txt”
watch_interval: 60

# CMD Job
insert_job: data_load_cmd_job
job_type: CMD
machine: localhost
command: bash loader_script.sh
condition: s(data_file_fw_job)
```